# How to dynamically chose a service to execute based on String with DI?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a String as input, and based on this I'd like to chose a `service` to execute.

For the following approach I'd have a delegator class that gets all possible services auto injected using `Spring 4`. But could improve this? Or is this a good approach to delegate to a speficic service?

Especially I don't know if injecting all my services that may be chosen based on the action in this class.

```
class Delegator {
    public MyService findService(String action) {
        switch (action) {
            case "A": return serviceA; break;
            case "B": return serviceB; break;
            //lots of other cases
        }
        return null; 
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyService serviceA;

    @Autowired
    private MyService serviceB;
}
```

Comment: Nice question, Waiting for answers! favourited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could have several solutions the easiest would be to create callback method on the `MyService` interface, you could then iterate over all `MyService` implementations and figure out which one to use (i.e. return `true` from the specified method when it is supported).

```
class Delegator {

    @Autowired
    private List<MyService> services;

    public MyService findService(String action) {
        for (MyService service : services) {
            if (service.canHandle(action) ) {
                return service
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not find service to handle: "+action);
    }

}
```

This allows you to add `MyService` implementations without having to modify your `Delegator` class.

A related/similair solution could be to use a `@Qualifier` annotation instead of adding a callback method on your `MyService` implementation. Your `Delegator` would have to be aware of springs `ApplicationContext` so that you could lookup the bean needed. The `@Qualifier` would of course be matched/related to the passed in the `action` method argument.

```
class Delegator {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory bf;

    public MyService findService(String action) {
        return BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(bf, MyService.class, action);
    }

}

@Service
@Qualifier("foo")
public MyService1 implements MyService { ... }

@Service
@Qualifier("bar")
public MyService2 implements MyService { ... }
```

For `action` matching *foo* the bean with `@Qualifier` foo would be returned. If no matching implementation could be found you will get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring's IoC container is meant to be domain independent. You seem to have very specific logic for determining a specific `MyService` instance. Your service locator is the appropriate pattern to use here.

Alternatively, if the logic is more complex, you can have your `MyService` interface declare a `supports` method. Your classes would implement this method to return `true` if they can support the action, or `false` otherwise. You would loop through all the services and return the first one to return `true`.
For example

```
@Autowired
private List<MyService> services;

public MyService findService(String action) {
    for(MyService service : services) {
        if(service.supports(action)) {
            return service;
        }
    }
    return null; // or whatever is appropriate
}
```